# Read only one order from orders textfile based on orderID

Tags: java

I am creating a system for a restaurant. 
I have an order textfile that saves the details of orders including the orderID. 
I want the user to be able to input an orderID and then ONLY this order is read from the textfile.

Currently I am able to read the whole textfile and display it in a jTextArea, this is my code:

```
String file_name = "login/orders.txt";

    try (BufferedReader accReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name))) 
        {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            int i;
            for(i=0; i<aryLines.length; i ++)
            {
                txtFullOrder2.append("\n" + aryLines[i]);

            }
        }
    catch (IOException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
            }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the format of `orders.txt`? It looks like you'll need to parse each line so you can find the one with the id you're looking for.

Comment: Each piece of information, order number, date etc. appears on a new line.  What do you mean by parse each line ? Sorry I'm new to java! @axblount